# Are refrigerated hard boild eggs really unsafe after a week?

Tags: food-safety, eggs, storage-lifetime, hard-boiled-eggs

Most sites that I've googled (such as http://www.ochef.com/1009.htm, and http://whatscookingamerica.net/Q-A/eggs2.htm) say that refrigerated hard-boiled eggs need to be eaten within one week.

I'm a little skeptical, and I know that many are very conservative where eggs are involved.

Can anyone point to an authoritative source that explains why, say 10-day old, refrigerated hard-boiled eggs would be unsafe?

Comment: Fascinating. In super markets here hard boiled eggs are sold without refrigeration around Easter. And surprisingly they don't usually go bad for at least two weeks *without* refrigeration. Unpeeled, of course. But that seems to be quite contradictory to the advice given in the answers to your question here. As far as I can remember from my childhood we ate hard boiled eggs from Easter even three weeks later without any issues.

Answer (score 24):

Yes, they really are unsafe after a week.

[According to the USDA](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/wcm/connect/fsis-content/internet/main/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/egg-products-preparation/shell-eggs-from-farm-to-table/ct_index#21) (similar information can be found from other food agencies):

> **Why do hard-cooked eggs spoil faster than fresh eggs?**
>
> When shell eggs are hard cooked, the protective coating is washed away, leaving bare the pores in the shell for bacteria to enter and contaminate it. Hard-cooked eggs should be refrigerated within 2 hours of cooking and used within a week.

Simply put, you're damaging the shell, and that expedites spoilage.  Some secondary sources such as [StillTasy](http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17147) (who use the agencies as their primary sources) are more liberal and say up to 2 weeks, but I'd at least give it a *very* thorough sniff test before eating hard-boiled eggs that old.  (And note that the sniff test will not necessarily alert you to bacterial contamination, only the more conventional forms of food spoilage like rancidity).

Comment: Shouldn't we rely more on the sniff test anyway rather than throwing out perfectly good food just because it's over the "best before" date?